# Get CSS properties values for a not yet applied class

Tags: jquery, css

In jQuery, I can get a CSS property value for a selector using the *css* method and passing a property name, for example:

`$('#myElement').css('backgroundImage');`

My question is, how can I get a css property value from a class that is **not** yet applied to **any** element? Similar to `$('.myClass').css('backgroundImage');` where the selector returns zero elements but there is a CSS declaration for that class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a temporary element without adding it to the DOM, and inspect the relevant property. CSS will apply, even if the element is not added to the DOM. E.g.

**CSS**

```
p { color: red; }
```

**JS**

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
alert(window.getComputedStyle(p, null).getPropertyValue('color'));
```

will give you the color value, but not add anything to the DOM.

**WARNING**

After a bit of research, I've determined that this method only works in Gecko-based browsers, so is not suitable for general-purpose use. This situation [may change in future](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#extensions-to-the-window-interface), but I wouldn't rely on this if you want a cross-browser solution today.

Given that, I would suggest you just create a temporary element, add the desired class, add it to the document, inspect it to get the style value, then remove it. You can additionally apply styles such as `display: none` to prevent it from being shown to the user during the incredibly brief time that it's part of the document.

Comment: Thank you @Bobby, its a nice solution as I don't have to add an element to the DOM

Comment: Won't that trigger an error on browsers that don't have a console? Like IE7/IE8?

Comment: I don't think this works. You need to add to the DOM http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/tuVhU/

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos: You're quite right in that the jQuery code did NOT work as expected in 'normal' code. I'd tested it in the console, and assumed that was good enough - obviously not! However, the plain javascript equivalent (obviously, not an *exact* equivalent) *does* work, so the element certainly doesn't need to be added to the DOM in order to get style values for it. Quite why the jQuery version doesn't work, I'm unsure - either $('<p/>') doesn't actually create an element at all, or .css() works slightly differently.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos: ... and that's not the end of this story: see my update above.

Comment: @BobbyJack +1 for improving your answer. I came across your answer, when I was also answering this other similiar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/10958973/607874 Essentially, we got the same solution.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You cannot get a css property from a class that is not applied to any element. However, you can directly read it from a CSS stylesheet and you can do this by using [DOM CSS](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html)

And then maybe have something like:

```
var bgimage = myStyleSheet.cssRules[0].style.background-image;
```

Comment: Thank you @wtrevino, it is nice to know that!