# jquery -Get CSS properties values for a not yet applied class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, width

i have a same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382858/get-css-properties-values-for-a-not-yet-applied-class#_=_) asked here(wasnt able to comment on it,maybe dont have a priviledge) , i want to get css width value defined in stylesheet but not yet applied on any element in dom ,(its bootstrap css with grid with responsive media queries)

```
 .span6 {
 width: 570px;
 }
```

However solution provided in above referenced question return 0  i.e like this

```
$('<div/>').addClass('span6').width();
```

but works if i do something like this

```
 $('<div/>').addClass('span6').hide().appendTo('body').width();
```

any easy way without appending that div?

Comment: If you REALLY (really) want to avoid inserting the element, you could make a map with the widths you need :p

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe there's an alternate / easier way to solve your issue?

Comment: The last time I saw a "get style properties with jquery" question it ended up with some regex as accepted answer, I guess your current solution is simple enough. You could call `.remove()` to clean the DOM after getting your desired CSS property value or always have a `display:none` element to apply the CSS to and get the value, removing the applied CSS class afterwards.

Comment: @MoinZaman i want to do some manipulation before deciding that particular class should be added or not, div has a image in  it ,its width can be anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get CSS properties values for a not yet applied class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382858/get-css-properties-values-for-a-not-yet-applied-class) - I was the author of the original 'bad' answer which has since been updated with more info.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to read a CSS property value from a nonexistent element, you need to dynamically insert that element (as hidden) to the DOM, read the property and finally remove it:

```
var getCSS = function (prop, fromClass) {

    var $inspector = $("<div>").css('display', 'none').addClass(fromClass);
    $("body").append($inspector); // add to DOM, in order to read the CSS property
    try {
        return $inspector.css(prop);
    } finally {
        $inspector.remove(); // and remove from DOM
    }
};
```

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/65bHm/)**

Comment: That's basically what OP is doing - `.css('display', 'none')` is virtually the same as `.hide()`, but +1 for expanding it to an usable function and the `finally` block which runs 'after' a `return`.

Comment: may be thats the only easy way to do it with "write less and do more jquery" :P

Comment: I've tried it for `background-position`, but it's returning `0% 0%` instead of the actual value...

Comment: @AlexFilipovici You should be doing something wrong. You can see here that works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/cVfFc/1/

Answer (score 4):

Great answer by Jose. I modified it to help with more complex css selectors.

```
var getCSS2 = function (prop, fromClass, $sibling) {

    var $inspector = $("<div>").css('display', 'none').addClass(fromClass);
    if($sibling != null){
        $sibling.after($inspector); //append after sibling in order to have exact 
    } else {
        $("body").append($inspector); // add to DOM, in order to read the CSS property
    }
    try {
        return $inspector.css(prop);
    } finally {
        $inspector.remove(); // and remove from DOM
    }
};
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2KX4/2/)**