# jQuery detect if css class has background image

Tags: jquery, css, background

I am trying to detect if a certain css class has a background-image applied to it.

I can simply do the following to test if a background-image is present:

```
if ($('.vc_custom_1498122672544').css('background-image') != 'none') {
  alert('There is a background image');
}
```

However the above class is generated dynamically, and will not always be known.

The div that has this class attached to it also has a few other classes applied. So i tried the following:

```
if ($('.vc_row-has-fill').css('background-image') != 'none') {
  alert('There is a background image');
}
```

This doesnt return anything as the background-image is specifically targeting the class of `.vc_custom_1498122672544` and not `.vc_row-has-fill`.

Is there anything i can do to detect the background-image with the class `.vc_row-has-fill`?

Comment: How many elements will have the class `vc_custom`?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013131/javascript-get-background-image-url-of-div - think you need to use `getComputedStyle` to get css from the stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

actually, you can check whether a class, has another class or not. For example, a div with class `.vc_row-has-fill` hasClass `.vc_custom_1498122672544` or not. if it does, then you could further check whether class `.vc_custom_1498122672544` has `background-image` or not

```
$('.vc_row-has-fill').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('vc_custom_1498122672544')){
       if ($('.vc_custom_1498122672544').css('background-image') != 'none') {
          alert('There is a background image');
        }
    }
});
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/9y52ef4c/

im not sure, whether this is what you want to achieve or not. hope will help

Comment: unfortunately the class "vc_custom_1498122672544" will be unknown as it is generated dynamically.

Comment: @danyo what do you mean by `unknown`? will the class name keep changing?

Comment: So when a new element is created in the backend, the custom class will be generated on the fly and will therefor be unknown.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, despite the fact that the class is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use the approach from this post:
[jquery -Get CSS properties values for a not yet applied class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958869/jquery-get-css-properties-values-for-a-not-yet-applied-class)

The code from there:

```
var getCSS = function (prop, fromClass) {

    var $inspector = $("<div>").css('display', 'none').addClass(fromClass);
    $("body").append($inspector); // add to DOM, in order to read the CSS property
    try {
        return $inspector.css(prop);
    } finally {
        $inspector.remove(); // and remove from DOM
    }
};
```

Basically you can call `getCSS('backgroundImage', ***A class to test for a background image***)` and use it for a method of elimination.

Does this help you in your situation?

Comment: this isnt working for me sorry! can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/65bHm/ - this fiddle is from the above post.

Comment: If you combine this with a loop and this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList - you should be good to go ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It should work ideally but if not then you can check if class like `vc_custom_1498122672544` always starting with `vc_custom_` and it always sets background to the element having class `vc_row-has-fill`, then you can check whether element has any class which starts with `vc_custom` like below.

```
if($(".vc_row-has-fill").is("[class*='vc_custom_']"))
{
   alert('There is a background image');
}
```

Or using function mentioned in the link posted by @hallleron you can check like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hasBackgroundImageSet(fromClass) {

   var $inspector = $("<div>").css('display', 'none').addClass(fromClass);
   $("body").append($inspector); 
   try {
     return $inspector.css('background-image') != 'none';
   } finally {
   $inspector.remove(); // and remove from DOM
 }
};


var hasBg = $(".vc_row-has-fill").attr("class").split(" ").some(function(cls) {
  return hasBackgroundImageSet(cls);
  //return $("."+cls).css("background-image") != "none";//use this if not use above
});

if(hasBg){
 alert('There is a background image');
} 

});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution i came up with. I know that the custom class is always the 3rd class applied to the div. Quite simple in the end:

```
$('.vc_row-has-fill').each(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    var imgClass = classes[3];
    if ($('.' + imgClass).css('background-image') != 'none') {
      alert('There is a background image');
    }
});
```