# How to get the CSS left-property value of a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

My CSS rule looks like this:

```css
#my-div{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -160px;
    bottom: -150px;
}
```

I'm trying to get value of the left-property like this:

- `document.getElementById('my-div').style.left`
- `document.getElementById('my-div').offsetLeft`

The problem is that both return `null`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem is that `someElement.style.left` only work if you have inline style. Since you apply your styling through a stylesheet, you will not be able to fetch the value the way you expect.

You have a couple of other approaches you could take to get the value through JavaScript:

**window.getComputedStyle:**

It is possible to get the computed style of an element using [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle), the problem is that it has quite limited support (IE9+). If you still want to use it you could wrap it up in a function to make it a bit easier to get each property:

```
function getCssProperty(elmId, property){
   var elem = document.getElementById(elmId);
   return window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(property);
}
// You could now get your value like
var left = getCssProperty("my-div", "left");
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/)**

**jQuery (or some other library):**

Another option would be to use a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (or whatever you prefer), which will provide you with a cross-browser solution to get the value.

With jQuery you could use the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to read the CSS-property of the element.

```
$(function () {
  var left = $("#my-div").css("left");
});
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/57e2m/1/)**
​

Comment: Does this work is the CSS has not been applied to an element? Can one read the CSS attributes of a CSS class even when the class has not been applied to any elements?

Comment: @dumbledad According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382972/678801) SO answer, gecko-based browsers would support creating a new element (without adding it to the DOM) and giving it a class, and then use getComputedStyle on the element to get the CSS. It appears to have limited support in other browsers though (haven't tested it myself).

Comment: Tried the jquery method, and I got "auto" back as a response. so this is not a universal solution

Comment: @PBo what css-property did you use it for, in which browser, and what value was you expecting? `auto` is the default value for the `left` property used in the example above for instance.

Comment: .css("left) property was what I was trying to use. I was using Chrome 60 (I think), It wasnt set and I had some other javascript code manipulating the other css properties. I gave up trying to get it. I think getClientRects return more accurate figures, but I gave up on that route

Answer (score 6):

You should call this

```
document.getElementById('my-div').style.left
document.getElementById('my-div').offsetLeft
```

when document is loaded, if you call it earlier it will return null because element doesnt exists yet. So you can use jQuery to determine when all content is loaded.

```
$(function() {
    //put your code here
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that, since CSS is loaded separately from the JS, there's no official way to ensure that the `style.left` property will be accurate. The `style.left` property is a different, higher-priority style override.

You'll need to use the `getComputedStyle` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Ex:

```
var div = document.getElementById('my-div');
var style = getComputedStyle(div);
var left = style.getPropertyValue("left");
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to call your functions after document ready.

If you use jQuery you can find left value faster:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var $left = $('#my-div').css('left');
     console.log($left);
 });
```

Comment: This returns null