# Figure out if an element is visible by its CSS using pure JavaScript or Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I know there is the visible() function in prototype. I cant use it though since it only checks for the inline style display:none. How can I check if an element is visible by looking at its CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `visible` ?

Comment: Do you mean just the target element itself, or any of its parents?  For example, the target element may be `display:block` but still be invisible if its parent element is `display:none`.  Also, an element may be considered invisible if its total (outer) width and height are 0.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the prototype [getStyle](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/getStyle/) function is what you are looking for, even though it got some limitations.
JQuery got the .css() method as meantioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778439/how-to-get-the-css-left-property-value-of-a-div-using-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The method `visible()` is working correct only for inline styles. Try instead:

```
$('your_element_id').getStyle('display')=='none'?0:1
```

to check if your element is visible or not.

Domus71