# How do you add the CSS 'left' property in a JavaScript conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to including a css "left" property to my javascript code such that if the left property in the css file matches the one in the javascript code, a certain action takes place. Any help will be appreciated.
The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<button id = "myBtn">MyButton<button>

<p id= "demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is:

```
#myBtn {
   position: absolute;
   left: 100px;
}
```

The script code is:

```
<script>
if (document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left == "100px") {
   actionX //this is just an example
   }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = actionX;
</script>
```

Comment: = is assignment, == tests for equality, === really tests for equality

Comment: Whoops, wrong duplicate.  Here's a better match:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866229/can-you-check-an-objects-css-display-with-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778439/how-to-get-the-css-left-property-value-of-a-div-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well you're setting the property value with the `=` operator, you want to use the `==` operator. In some rare unusual cases which I can't seem to think of, you'd do an assignment in an if statement, but setting a property of an object will return a truthy value in JS, so the branch will always be reached.

```
if (document.getElementById("demo").style.left == "100px") {
    actionX (just an example) 
}
```